# Connecting Oracle to Microsoft SQL Server on 2 different servers

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, heterogeneous-services

I am trying to make a connection between Oracle and SQL Server to insert some values from Oracle into SQL Server. I have 2 questions which i was hoping you can help.

There is a stored procedure created in Oracle 11g database. It joins a few tables together and pushes the values into a table called `my_table` in SQL Server.

The issue/question I have: I've tried to make a connection between Oracle and SQL Server using this link: Making a Connection from Oracle to SQL Server - Page 2 — DatabaseJournal.com

The instruction is however for when Oracle and SQL Server are on a same server.

As is my case  Oracle is on one server and SQL Server is on another, I am struggling to understand the concept of setting up Listener and tbs.

Do I have to do any configuration on SQL Server? Do I need to create the DNS on SQL Server?

When I create a DNS in Oracle server, the connection to SQL Server is successful (port 1433) but I'm not sure how to alter my Listener and TNS for that.

My Oracle knowledge is not advanced but so far I've managed to get to this point. Hope you can help me resolve the last bit of the puzzle.